# Crash issue: iOS 12.0.1 ( 16A404 ), App closed automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

I have a crash issue, the App closed automatically.The version iOS 12.0.1 ( 16A404 ). iPhone 7.

The exception is as following.

```
0x1ab734dfc <+120>: bl     0x1ab864eb4               ; symbol stub for: qos_class_main
    0x1ab734e00 <+124>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x1ab734e04 <+128>: mov    x1, x19
    0x1ab734e08 <+132>: mov    x2, #0x0
    0x1ab734e0c <+136>: bl     0x1ab862db0               ; pthread_sigmask
    0x1ab734e10 <+140>: bl     0x1ab8645a8               ; pthread_self
    0x1ab734e14 <+144>: orr    w1, wzr, #0x6
    0x1ab734e18 <+148>: bl     0x1ab8651cc               ; symbol stub for: _pthread_setcancelstate_exit$VARIANT$mp
    0x1ab734e1c <+152>: mov    w0, #0x2710
    0x1ab734e20 <+156>: bl     0x1ab70c75c               ; usleep$NOCANCEL
    0x1ab734e24 <+160>: orr    w8, wzr, #0xffffffe7
    0x1ab734e28 <+164>: str    w8, [sp, #0x18]
    0x1ab734e2c <+168>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x1ab734e30 <+172>: mov    x1, x19
    0x1ab734e34 <+176>: mov    x2, #0x0
    0x1ab734e38 <+180>: bl     0x1ab754644               ; symbol stub for: __printf_exec
->  0x1ab734e3c <+184>: brk    #0x1
```

I do not know Assembly well. I use `bt`.

Seen from 'serial.umeng.sdk.queue', I think it is a third service issue in China.

```
ZTO:[AppDelegate.m LineNum:90]  reason: [<UIStatusBarTimeItemView 0x1052660a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _timeString.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) bt
* thread #4, queue = 'serial.umeng.sdk.queue', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00000001ab7dd104 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001ab8580e0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
    frame #2: 0x00000001ab734e1c libsystem_c.dylib`__abort + 152
    frame #3: 0x00000001ab734d84 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 152
    frame #4: 0x00000001aadfcf78 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 132
    frame #5: 0x00000001aadfd120 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #6: 0x00000001aae15e48 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
    frame #7: 0x00000001aae090fc libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #8: 0x00000001aae09188 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 84
    frame #9: 0x00000001aae15da4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 12
    frame #10: 0x0000000104f90df8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 36
    frame #11: 0x0000000104f92e44 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_once_callout + 84
    frame #12: 0x0000000104f8f840 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #13: 0x0000000104f90de4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #14: 0x0000000104f98e88 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 720
    frame #15: 0x0000000104f99b7c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 460
    frame #16: 0x0000000104fa3c18 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 1220
    frame #17: 0x00000001ab8620f0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 312
    frame #18: 0x00000001ab864d00 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

Want to know more about how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the crash log is suffice for you to solve the issue.

> reason: [ valueForUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _timeString.

The object `_timeString` is somehow missing its connection to the interface builder (if you're using it). If you're not using IB, then check out other people's solutions here: [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)